# Create a view Table in python

Tags: python, tableview

I would like to know is there any widget like c# (Data Grid View) that displays the data in row and column?
I retrieve data from postgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

The pandas library (http://pandas.pydata.org/), specifically the DataFrame.  You can display the table in multiple formats, from HTML (if you're using IPython Notebook, for example) to LaTeX via the functions to_html() or to_latex(), as well as a tabbed printing for working from a console.  It does not give you interactive editing within the display, but you can view any portion of the data.  It can also read sql directly into a Data Frame.

Comment: Pandas works just like any other library in python. You can import it in your code just as you would import numpy or scipy.  It would just be an additional required python library for your desktop application.